# Is it possible for the color to 'erase' the background in CSS?

Tags: html, css, colors, transparency

I really doubt what I am asking is possible but it's still worth a try.

I am trying to create a button that normally has `background-color: transparent; color: white;` and when you hover over it, those properties should swap. The problem is that if you just swap them then all you see is a white button. If you know the background colour of the containing element then you can get the colour from there but If the button is over an image or a canvas then this won't work.

This is how I've been doing it so far

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  background-color: #38404D;
  height: 100%;
}

.ghost-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  outline: none !important;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 6px 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ghost-button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #38404D;
}

.ghost-button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 0px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="ghost-button">Hover Here</button>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that quite a few people were confused by the question. I am asking if there is a way to do the exact same thing I've done above but on top of an image or a canvas (instead of a solid colour). See example below

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  background-image: url("http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/17878-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.ghost-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  outline: none !important;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 6px 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ghost-button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #38404D;
}

.ghost-button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 0px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="ghost-button">Hover Here</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try something like this? https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: yes its possible

Comment: I'm not sure to understand at all, but if the desidered effect is that the button background color is equal to background of the underlying container, why can't you keep `background-color:trasparent;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it **IS** possible in CSS with `mix-blend-mode`.

**Answer's update in April 2021:** Currently it have a [very solid support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode) (95% globally) although Safari doesn't have `hue`, `saturation`, `color`, and `luminosity` blend modes. Of course, IE isn't a considerable thing if you expect to use it (like many of other cool CSS features of the last years).

```css
.ghost-button {
  /* Important part */
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;

  /* Button cosmetics */
  border: .125em solid #fff;
  font: 2em/1 Cursive;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  outline: none !important;
  transition: all .8s;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ghost-button:hover {
  /* Important part */
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

#container {
  background: url('http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/17878-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg') center/cover;

  /* Also works with background-color or gradients: */
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow); */

  /* Container positioning */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="ghost-button">Hover Here</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the secret here is using `mix-blend-mode: screen` along with the `black` color for the "erased" part, since black is mixed with the background when using this `screen` mode.

Comment: Thanks, great answer but could you possibly minimise your example (remove the font and everything else that is not required) or add another snippet / code block?

Comment: Will this also work for `background-color` or only for `background-image` ?

Comment: @nickzoum sorry for the delay, I updated the answer commenting the code based on your new questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible in CSS! You could try to set the `color` with JS to mimic this effect.

Comment: Still wouldn't work with image or canvas though. Would it?

Comment: And I'm guessing it's not possible for the colour to inherit the parent's background colour?

Comment: True, but you would have to listen for mutations to do this for elements that are added later on.

Comment: Man, it IS possible with CSS.